# Запись файла в PHP

Tags: php, файлы

Вот пишем мы фаил
допустим он большой
и пишется 5 минут
на второй минуте интернет упал
у нас фаил будет же все равно? Только не доконца забитый?
или файла не будет?

```
 try {
            while (!empty($line = $response->getBody()->read(1024))) {
                fwrite($handle, $line, 1024);
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln($e->getMessage());     
        } finally {
            fclose($handle);
        }
```

Comment: Ммм....отключите сервер (на локальном компе..т.к. инет отключение это тоже самое, по сути) во время проверки и посмотрите)

Comment: Сделал)
Часть файла записалось

Comment: А ведь просто было получить ответ на свой вопрос, правда?